# ios double from string without rounded

Tags: iphone, ios, double, rounding

Below code is rounding my latitude string. i dont want it to get rounded. double lat must be 41.04546.

```
NSString *latitude= @"41.04546";
double lat= latitude.doubleValue;  //it gives 41.0455
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinat;
coordinat.latitude= lat;
```

For precise coordinate that must not be rounded.

Comment: That code works fine for me, it prints out: 41.045460

Comment: What method have you used to know it is 41.0455? Maybe the rounding occurs on printing the value without enough precission

Comment: i see the lat is 41.0455 in debugging console.

Comment: @Maik639  i can print out without no problem as well. but i cant assign to double without rounding.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try with this line..

```
NSString *latitude= @"41.04546";
double lat= [latitude doubleValue];
NSLog(@"\n\n Value Lat ==>> %f",lat);
```

Comment: i also did try. it gave same result.

Comment: @bselvan i use this code and i got out put is  Value Lat ==>>  41.045460

Comment: yes it result 41.045460 in output console. but in the left panel (local variables values) it seems 41.0455.

Comment: and you want to assign this value to latitude and longitude then you can use float value, mate.. i use it ..

Comment: ok. but i cant understand why it seems 41.0455 in local variable panel. it mislead me. i was thinking i have focus the map on wrong point.

Comment: no no mate try to use float value see i use this type of logic in my app and get output like this.. Lat = 23.039568 Long = 72.566002 , so just do somthing with code and use float value instead of double , may be you got output which you want.. :)

Comment: i test it on google maps. it gives me same point where my app focus. So in spite of seeming 41.0455 in local variable panel,in fact my code is processing lat as 41.04546. Likewise NSLog prints out same result.

Comment: oh ok but now you have any problem about it?? means not any problem now??

Comment: no. i havent any problem now. thanks for your answer. it would be good displaying double without rounding in xcode debugging. it mislead someone like me and cause finding a solution for one hour in vain :-(

Answer (score 2):

Use NSNumberFormatter

```
- (NSNumber *)numberFromString:(NSString *)string

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init]; 
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"41.04546"];       
NSLog(@"Number : %@ , Double value : %f",number,[number doubleValue]);   

Output:Number : 41.04546 , Double value : 41.045460
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i have searched for NSNumberFormatter. but i couldnt find out. Can you write code?

Comment: NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter  numberFromString:@"41.04546"];
    NSLog(@"Number : %@ , Double value : %f",number,[number doubleValue]);
Output:Number : 41.04546 , Double value : 41.045460